# Sftp credentials working in winscp but not in command line

Tags: linux, command-line, putty, shell-script, sftp

I have a windows server which I also log into via putty. On the windows server, i have winscp with saved and working logins. From winscp > Generate Session URL, I can get a specific accounts login details (username, password, server, etc.). Now when i try to manually execute an sftp command from the putty session, i can get to the password part of the command but it wont accept the login. Here is the command I use on the command line:

```
sftp -oPort=00000 username@server
```

Why was the credentials working on winscp but not on the command line? How to make i work from the command line?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Permissions?  Are you running putty as Admin?

Comment: Yes. I am using admin account.

Comment: When you run Putty, did you right click and Run as Administrator?  That is different than being in an Admin Acccount

Comment: Yes. I've opened the putty as admin (run as admin)

Comment: Thank you.  I do not know then why one method works and the other does not.

Comment: Is the port really 00000? Does it accept `sftp -P XXX user@server`?

Comment: I just installed OpenSSH on a Win10 client. SFTP into a remote system with the command I specified works as expected. Connecting with PuTTY to the remote system then executing the same command on the remote system command line to connect to another remote system with the same command also works. If this doesn't work for you, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1778360/edit) your question to add step-by-step workflow you use, preferably with screenshots, that can be analyzed and if necessary replicated.

Comment: Logging into the Win system with PuTTY, then giving command `sftp -oPort=<port> user@server` to further SFTP into another remote system works also as expected. I'm running PuTTY as system admin, but not starting it as administrator.

Comment: Why did you post your question with one account and then [suggest an edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1183191) from a different account with a similar name?